# Are Transit Visas for Germany required for our group?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, dual-nationality, frankfurt

We are 3 family members traveling together. We hold a Palestinian Authority passport, an Egyptian passport, and a Jordanian passport. We have a 3 hour layover/transit in Frankfurt, Germany, then we continue to Kiev, Ukraine.

Do each of us need a transit visa for this 3 hours layover?

Note: Each of us has a valid visa to Ukraine